# Windows System File (.SYS)

Tags: windows

What is a Windows System File (.SYS)? How the Windows invoke these files?

Comment: they are device drivers..

Comment: @user280140 - SO is about programming questions, and since your question is not one, it will probably get closed and moved to SuperUser.com, which is a better forum for this kind of question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

they are device drivers. When installed they have certain registry values on when to invoke them. They usually run in kernel space